# Based on condition add true or false

Tags: javascript, angular

I've 5 cells in a table. If the value are empty for those cells i need to disable them.

I can do something like this for each cells which work's.

```
function cellOne(params) {
    if (params.value === null || params.value === undefined) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

"CellOne": { disabled:cellOne }
```

is there any other way to check null value of each cell and add disable property instead of creating multiple function for each cells. Please help

Comment: Can you provide some HTML?

Comment: could you provide the template and component logic you are using ? Its hard to understand the problem with only such infos

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to go for typescript code.You can do it in the template itself.

```
<your-cell [disabled]="!params.value"></your-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function would return the same thing as :

```
function cellOne(params) {
    return params.value != null 
}
```

which you can easily inline instead of having a separate function for that.

To check for params that might be null or undefined too, you can use :

```
return params && params.value != null
```